# How to use Python implemented GDAL utilities via OSGeo4W Shell?

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo4w

Following installation of QGIS v 3.10.1 on a W10 machine, I am automatically hooked up with OSGeo4W Shell. From there, I can directly invoke gdal utilities such as `gdalinfo` and `gdal_translate`. However, other utilities fail me, such as `gdal_edit` and `pct2rgb`, even though they are listed alongside each other at the gdal raster programs [website](https://gdal.org/programs/#raster-programs).

It appears that `gdal_edit` and the likes are implemented in Python, quoting from [OSGeo4W site](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-gdal):

> To get the commandline utilities implemented in Python (like gdal_merge, and rgb2pct), install gdal-python.

Reading up on [gdal-python](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/pkg-gdal-python) says:

> The standard scripts, like rgb2pct.py, are placed in osgeo4w\bin and include .bat wrapper scripts

This is as far as I get. I can't find the mentioned location, nor any .bat wrapper scripts. The nearest I can get is: `c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Scripts\gdal_edit.py` but I am lost how to employ this script to my needs.

How can I use `gdal_edit`?

Comment: There should be nothing special to do. Do you get a list of commands from the OSGeo4W shell with command `o-help`?

Comment: Yes, I get a list of about 142 commands. However, gdal_edit is not among them

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. I've used an Anaconda Python environment created earlier, which as among others, `geopandas` installed. Then I can run: `>python "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Scripts\gdal_edit.py" -unsetnodata c:\apps\images\dummy_image.tif`

Comment: It is not quite as it is supposed to be used but if it works just go ahead. Still have a look at some environment variables that OSGeo4W sets like PYTHONHOME and path. Also notice that for example command `gdal_edit` is supposed to run script `gdal_edit.bat` in the \bin directory. The gdal_edit.bat looks like this `@echo off 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat" 
python "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdal_edit.py" %* `